VBA Excel looping with formula
I would like to make a loop with the formula defined in Excel with the VBA Function.
The function can be found here:
https://trumpexcel.com/extract-numbers-from-string-excel/
where the typical formula looks like:
  =GetNumeric(TEXTBEFORE(AD5,","))

although I don't want to mess around with additional columns, so I decided to use them as the VBA formula.
My code could look like this:
 For jr = 5 To jlRow
 If bws.Cells(jr, "X").Value <> "" Then
 dws.Range("E1") = "=GetNumeric(TEXTBEFORE("&bws.Cells(jr, "AD").Value&",','))"
 End If
 Next jr

but unfortunately this approach doesn't work with the apostrophes and quotes.
How could I manage with the formula such as this?

Note that bws.Cells(jr, "AD").Value is not the same as AD5. If you're passing the cell value, you likely need to enclose it within quotes. Also see how to put double quotes in a string

Yes, it's not, but the AD5 AD6, etc should be the result of looping.

My point was that the cell value is not the same as the cell address. If you want the formula to look like AD5, then "=GetNumeric(TEXTBEFORE(AD" & jr

And then, quotes should be doubled: ","",""))"

Are you sure that wanting changing the value of the same cell (dws.Range("E1"))? Shouldn't the code iterate its row, too?

You should try "=GetNumeric(TEXTBEFORE(" & bws.Cells(jr, "AD").Address & ","",""))", or simpler (as suggested above) "=GetNumeric(TEXTBEFORE(AD" & jr & ","",""))". Besides that, please look at my previous comment. It sounds strange to place the formula result in the same cell, overwriting the precedent value... Shouldn't it be dws.Range("E" & jr) = "=GetNumeric(TEXTBEFORE(" & bws.Cells(jr, "AD").Address & ","",""))"?

I tried: dws.Range("E1") = "=GetNumeric(TEXTBEFORE(" & bws.Cells(jr, "'&bws&'!AD").Address & ","",""))"
but no values are returned

Because what you tried is wrong. In VBA you need to let space before an after & to build part of the formula in case of returning something. Please, try exactly how I suggested above. And also take care of incrementing the cell row where the formula to return...

The same effect. In fact your formula could be correct, but the mother tab is missing, the value is taken from the duplicated tab

I do not understand what  does "the mother tab is missing". I only tried reproducing the formula you show in your question...

@FaneDuru the output formula looks like this: =@GetNumeric(TEXTBEFORE($AD$159,","))
which means that the sheet bws has been completely missed here.

I cannot see the sheet in formula you posted =GetNumeric(TEXTBEFORE(AD5,",")). What do you want, in fact? If without showing that "sheet" you ask about something about we do cannot know anything, how to be helped? Why, at least now, you do not show the formula exactly as you want it? As I said above, I tried reproducing the single element I could see, respectively the formula from your question. I cannot remember since when I could see a question so bad formulated against what you try saying in comments...

I would like to have the sheet like =GetNumeric(TEXTBEFORE('bws'!AD5," , ")) and can't be successful with my approaches.
